# Multi Threading terminate thread and give access to other thread

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a code like below

```
public static void loginModule() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter username:");
        String username = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter password:");
        String password = sc.next();
        if(TicketManager.loginValidation(username, password)) {
            seatsAvailable();
            bookSeats();
            bookingConfirmation();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Details");
            loginModule();
        }
    }


public static synchronized boolean userOption(String userOption) {
        if(userOption.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Transaction completed your seat number is: "+seatNumber);
            return true;
        }else if(userOption.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            System.out.println("Your session is closed");
            //want to put wait method here
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm calling the userOption() method in bookingConformation() method, When the user enters 'no' the current thread should stop executing and give access to the next thread.

meanwhile if i have 
int value = 0;
if user enters 'no'
i want to assign value = 1; after 3mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a time waiting here like wait(3000) and by this the other thread who is waiting will automatically get the control to access this method -userOption.